# How to unlock ZTE ZXHN F660

Tags: networking, firmware, fiber, bridge-router, optical-network-terminal

When i try to activate bridge mode

- go to WAN settings and add new connection
- in type select box, only **route** choice is available
- I have to inspect the select element to add an option bridge
- when i select the bridge option added manually, the interface change to the bridge configuration
- after submit, the bridge configuration saves successfully but when i reload the page it becomes to **route** mode.

I think that the bridge mode is disabled by ISP in the router firmware, as the router interface has the logo if the IPS.

Now I'm looking for a way to unlock the router to be able to change the setting to bridge mode.

[image: screenshot]